# Points at distance $k$ or less in 2D grid

Tags: combinatorics

How can we prove that the total number of mesh points k or fewer jumps away from an arbitrary point in a 2D mesh is: $2k^2 + 2k + 1$.

I tried making a $3 \times 3$ mesh.

```
     a --- b --- c
     |     |     |
     d --- e --- f
     |     |     |
     g --- h --- i
```

For point $e$, the number of points $k=1$ jump away is four: $b$, $d$, $f$, $h$.
But, according to the formula, it should be $2\times1^2 + 2\times1 + 1=5$.
I am stuck!

Comment: The point $e$ itself is also at 1 of fewer jumps away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ on a 2D mesh is $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$. You can prove this as follows:

- Every horizontal edge changes the $x$ coordinate by one, hence we need at least $|x_1-x_2|$ horizontal edges. Similarly we need $|y_1-y_2|$ vertical edges. This shows that the distance is at least $|x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2|$.
- On the other hand, it's not hard to find a path taking exactly $|x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2|$ many edges (exercise).

Now say that the fixed point is $(0,0)$. You are interested in the number of points $(x,y)$ such that
$$ |x| + |y| \leq k. $$
This is something you can solve on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Read your question more carefully. The formula you give is for

> the total number of mesh points $k$ **or fewer** jumps away

(my emphasis).  And there are indeed five points one jump or fewer away from $e$: $b$, $d$, $f$, $h$ and $e$ itself.